# What is time complexity of below code?

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop, math, time-complexity

```
For(I=1 ; I<=n ; I++)
{
    For(J=1 ; J<=I ; J++)
        {
             For(K=1 ; K<=n^5 ; K=15 × K)
                 {
                      x=y+z;
                 }
        }  
}
```

It seems to be O(N^2 log N) according to me, but when i analyzed the k loop, it is not following the Log N, which is confusing me,

Comment: Why don't you share the analysis you did too then? :)

Comment: Note that K<=n^5.  K=15*K is a linear progression compared to an exponential progression (a progression which doesn't depend on n!)

Comment: Last loop is not following O(logn). I checked for N =15,20,23,26...

Comment: For a big n imagine comparing n^5 with 15^n . Which one will be increase incredibly faster? Obviously 15^n . So `For(K=1 ; K<=n^5 ; K=15 × K)` loop instantly break because of the condition and you can ignore time complexity of this loop. Answer is O(n^2).

Comment: @jarred has answered. It Is diferent

Comment: That would be accurate if the n^5 were devided by the 15^n, but it's not, they're combined differently. Your way effectively assumes the entire loop is constant time, which is clearly false. The number of iterations clearly grows with N.

Comment: @Mooing, then i think O(n^2 logN) is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time complexity of your problem is:

[image]

**Explanation:**

When we say

[image]

we mean

[image]

**not**

[image]

2 base of log function is coming from **divide by 2** in the definitions inside of for loops about binary searching not from the binary nature of computers.

But in your case divide by value is not 2 but 15 because of `k = 15 × k` definition so the base of log function must be 15 not 2.

You can see the correlation between these with replacing `k *= 15` line with `k *= 2` and

```
print n * n * int(math.log(n**5,15) + 1)
```

line with

```
print n * n * int(math.log(n**5,2) + 1)
```

in the given Python Code above. Results will continue to match.

Also because of the quitting of binary base you need to round up log function with [nearest integer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_integer_function):

[image]

**Python Code:**

```
import math

n = 100
i = 1
while i <= n:
    j = 1
    while j <= i:
        k = 1
        counter = 1
        while k <= n**5:
            x = 1 + 1
            k *= 15
            counter += 1
        #print k
        #print counter
        j += 1
    #print j
    i += 1
#print i

print "\nTime Complexity Prediction:"
print n * n * int(math.log(n**5,15) + 1)

print "\nReal World Result:"
print (i - 1) * (j - 1) * (counter - 1)
print ""
```

**Example results of the program:**

For n = 10:

```
Time Complexity Prediction:
500

Real World Result:
500
```

For n = 100:

```
Time Complexity Prediction:
90000

Real World Result:
90000
```

For n = 1000:

```
Time Complexity Prediction:
13000000

Real World Result:
13000000
```

For n = 3000:

```
Time Complexity Prediction:
135000000

Real World Result:
135000000
```

Comment: Can u elaborate complexity more?

Comment: @stackuser Please tell me, which part of the expression needs more explanation?

Comment: While your ultimate conclusion is technically correct, big-O notation eats constant factors and log bases, so you should just simplify the whole thing to O(n^2 log n).

Comment: @templatetypedef I was trying to prevent calculation mistakes for testing purposes so I did not simplify the expression but you are correct.

Comment: @templatetypedef: To clarify, big-O notation eats log bases because they're only a constant factor apart, so: big-O eats constant factors (and ergo, log bases). However, I don't think you can simply eat the `n^5` in the middle.

Comment: @MooingDuck log (n^5) = 5 log n = O(log n).

Comment: I would either (1) say the answer is exactly n(n+1)log_15(n^5) / 2 or just say O(n^2 log n). Mixing and matching the notation is mathematically misleading.

Comment: @templatetypedef: I verified that as accurate. So yeah. O(n^2 log n)

Answer (score 5):

It should be `O(n^2 log(n))` because the inner loop will be called `(n/2)(n+1)` times and it will loop log base 15 of `n^5 = 5 * log base 15` of n because k grows exponentially in the number of loops.

This results in `5(n^2+n)(log base 15 of n)/2` assignments to x, which is `O(n^2 * log(n))`

Comment: How you came up with (n/2)(n + 1) times?

Comment: The sum of 1+2+3+4+...+n=(n/2)(n+1) because there are n/2 pairs that each add up to n+1 being added. Your second loop will run once the first time, twice the second, three times the third, and so on up to n, so this fits.

Answer (score -1):

Actually it is `15BaseLog(n)`

Now, look at the powers of `15` : `15, 225, 3375, 50625, 759375, 11390625, ......`

See how fast they grow. When you run the `2nd inner loop`, the effect is ignorable, because this sequence (power of 15) passes the value on `n` before a countable number of iterations.

That's why, There is no significant effect of `log(n)`

Comment: log base a of n = O(log base b of n) because each one can be multiplied by a constant factor to be greater than the other. f(x) is O(g(x)) if there exists some values c and n such that for all x>n, f(x)<=cg(x). Because of the change of base property, the value of c is 1/(log base b of a) and any positive value can be chosen for x.

Comment: No, this is incorrect. All logs with constant bases are asymptotically equivalent to one another.

Comment: Thanks @both. Sorry, my mistake. I confused the idea of `big-O`. I actually explained why it's not following the `log(n)` part.

Comment: It's fixed now :)